# How to get Shutter Edit feature to open images in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, screenshot, image-processing, shutter

I often take screenshots with Shutter, and after doing this, I sometimes wish to edit them, so I am forced to open GIMP and then find them in my file system to edit, as the built-in image editor in Shutter isn't very good, or at least I can't get the hang of it. But I was wondering if there is a any way (to save time) of getting it to open the image in GIMP instead of the built-in image editor when clicking the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button in Shutter?

However please note that I do not want the image once saved to be automatically opened in GIMP, I only want it to open in GIMP if I click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button in Shutter.

---

I am using Ubuntu 15.04

Package information:

```
shutter:
  Installed: 0.92-0.1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.92-0.1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.92-0.1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: It's written in Perl, should be easy to patch =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 options. Of course, both require `shutter` and `gimp` to be installed:

### A - How to open every screenshot automatically with GIMP:

Simply open the Shutter window and click in the menu line on `Edit` --> `Preferences` (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) or if the Shutter icon already shows up in the panel, click on it and select `Preferences` from the drop-down menu.

Choose the tab `Actions` on the left side and you will see a window like in the screenshot below. Here you may switch the application with which you want to perform edits by selecting another one from the list labelled `Open with:`.

---

### B - How to disable automatic editor opening and open a single screenshot manually with GIMP:

1. **Disable automatic editor launching:**
   Open Shutter and go to `Preferences` --> `Actions` as described in detail in part A of this answer. There, *disable* the checkbox `Open with:`. What program is selected in the list is irrelevant, as it will be ignored.
2. **Open a single screenshot with GIMP:**
   After normally making the screenshot with Shutter, the main window appears (no editor, as we unchecked this in step 1 before). In the menu `Screenshot`, you navigate to the submenu `Open with`, where you may chose any recognized image editing application to launch and open the current screenshot.

   [image: IMAGE<Shutter main window - Menu 'Screenshot' - Open with - GIMP>]

Answer (score 0):

None of this works. But if you install shutter from their ppa and not from included in ubuntu packages, everything will work fine.

To remove old shutter:

```
sudo apt-get remove shutter
```

To install proper version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install shutter
```